# How to store a color label in Xcode 10.2.1 from iOS 9.3

Tags: swift, xcode, userdefaults

I'm making a game, and I want to save that when I pass the level, the background of the button changes color. Is it correct to use UserDefaults?

For example, the button "level 1" the background is gray and when the level is completed the color changes to orange but when I close the app, the button "level 1" returns to its gray color.

How do I save the color of the button in this case orange when the level is completed?

I've tried to use userDefaults but when defining it it tells me "UIColor cannot be converted to String"

```
@IBAction func continuarAccion(_ sender: Any) {  


    animateOut(desireView: vistaNivel1).  //Remove the view, in this case I have a blur, is where the level is shown

    botonNivel1.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}
```

By default, the background button "level 1", is white
when the level is complete the "level 1 button" changes the background to orange.

I would like to know how I can save that orange color so that when I close the app, the background of the "level 1" button remains orange.

Is it correct for me to use Userefaults?

I'm using xcode 10.1.2, compatibility from iOS 9.3

Comment: save hex value in nsuserdefaults instead of UIColor..

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'Any?' to type 'UIColor?'

Comment: what is your code to save in nsuserdefaults?

Answer (score 0):

save hex value to userdefaults:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set( hexValue as? String, forKey: "color")
```

// get value

```
    let strColor = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "color") as? String
```

//   To convert hex value to UIColor:

```
   func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```